# Twitter: Twitter4j User's Country

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I'm using twitter4j to get the location of a Twitter user:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
long id = accessToken.getUserId();
User user = twitter.showUser(id);

System.out.print("LOCATION: " +user.getLocation());
```

`user.getLocation()` does not include the country. How to get the user's country using twitter4j?

Answer (score 1):

There's no separate field for a user's country.  Whatever information is set in the Location field on your Twitter Profile page should be returned by the `getLocation()` method.

One thing I noticed about your code is that you're not showing how the accessToken variable is initialized.  Try the following:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
long id = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET).getUserId();
User user = twitter.showUser(id);
System.out.print("LOCATION: " + user.getLocation());
```

Where `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` are the values you get after granting your application permission to access your Twitter account on your [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) page.  When I run the code above I get the expected: "LOCATION: Charlotte, NC USA"